# Foreground service killed by Doze Mode

Tags: android, kotlin, service, foreground-service

I'm running a foreground service when the app goes into background and sending latitude and longitude to a server every 10 seconds , the issue is that the foreground service keeps only sending data when on foreground or in background  it keeps sending data until the phone screen turns off and after a while it stops working and the foreground service is cleared .. i'm not really sure what to do about this case , i have also whitelisted the app for battery optimization but did not work ..

- Starting service from my location code

```
    locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(location: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(location)
                val latitude = location.lastLocation.latitude
                val longitude = location.lastLocation.longitude
                val serviceIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity,LocationService::class.java)
                serviceIntent.putExtra("latitude",latitude)
                serviceIntent.putExtra("longitude",longitude)
                startService(serviceIntent)

            }
```

- My Service and sending data into server

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class LocationService : Service() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedPreferences  : SharedPreferences
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val latitude  = intent?.getDoubleExtra("latitude",0.0)
        val longitude = intent?.getDoubleExtra("longitude",0.0)
        postValuesToServer(latitude!!, longitude!!)
        showNotification(latitude,longitude)

       
        return START_STICKY
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun showNotification(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent   = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        val notificationCompat = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,Utils.NOTIFICATION_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Longitud : $longitude")
            .setContentText("Latitud : $latitude")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_circle_notifications_24)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            startForeground(1,notificationCompat)
        }
        else {
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(1,notificationCompat)
        }
    }
```

- Service Added To Manifest File

```
   <service android:name=".services.LocationService"
         android:foregroundServiceType="location|dataSync"/>
```

Comment: have you tested LocationCallback in the Service object? for clarification: start the service first, then in the Service start to listen to the location callback

Comment: Thank you , Will try and let you know

Comment: It is the same thing as soon as i turn off the screen , the foreground service is killed , is there anyway to bypass the doze mode in my case ?

Comment: Could Fcm be an alternative in my case ?

Comment: Are you sure about killing service by closing the screen? would you check with the START_NOT_STICKY return value?

Comment: Yeah when screen is off , the foreground service gets killed by Doze Mode , if you try it in Lollipop , it will work pretty fine because the Doze mode was introduced from android marshmellow and up , i tried almost everything but it keeps being killed unfortunately , i'm stuck ..

Comment: I am wondering bcoz we are using the same thing in Android 7 to 13 and it works fine.

Comment: Do you have any code snippet to take a look at if you do not mind for sure ?